# How to create a linux user using nodejs

Tags: linux, node.js, server

I have seen `npm adduser`, but i can figure it out how to manage this inside mine code.
What i have to do is to create new user from nodejs server code inside linux server, and change chmod and chown of that user and folders it content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [child_process.execFile](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) to execute `/usr/sbin/adduser`, `/bin/chmod` and `/bin/chown`

Otherwise you can use [exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec) from npm if your version of nodejs doesn't have child_process.execFile

Comment: Doing this from a node process assumes the process is running as 'root', which is a __bad__ idea. The proper way would be to add the user under which the process will run to the /etc/sudoers file with the proper magic to __only__ run `useradd` as root without a password. See http://www.ducea.com/2006/05/19/linux-tips-the-proper-way-to-allow-regular-users-to-run-commands-as-root/

Comment: I agree with @RobRaisch and do what he said, but with exec i cant use sudo, or just cant find how. Without sudo working perfectly